# Can I override SaveChangesAsync() for all my repositories?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, repository, blazor-server-side, savechanges

I have a pretty large Blazor project where I have some small repositories (for simple entities) that derive from a GenericRepository like

```
public class MySmallRepositoryOne : GenericRepository<MySmallEntityOne>, IMySmallRepositoryOne
```

But I also have Repositories for more complex entities that doens't derive from GenericRepository.

Are there a way to make an

```
public override int SaveChangesAsync()
{
    // my code

    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

that override SaveChangesAsync() for all repositories? Or does every repository need to derive from Generic and it's in generic I put this override?

Comment: Such code means you're misusing EF *badly*. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit of Work, it *owns* the actual Repositories, ie DbSets. Which are *already* generic. If you call `SaveChanges` from your CRUD class (that's what it is, despite the name), you'll persist all the changes made by all other CRUD classes. The "repository" recipe you tried is an ugly *anti*pattern

Comment: Why do you want to override it?

Comment: I have a baseclass where I have CreatedDate and ModifiedDate and alot of other class derive from this baseclass.  I will that my SaveChangesAsync update those 2 param so I don't need to create code for this manueall everytime I have code that call SaveChangesAsync()..  Maybe there is better way to handle CreatedDate/ModifiedDate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could override "savechanges" in specific "xxxDbContext". But SaveChangesAsync should be written asynchronously to use await. Needn't derive every repository.

```
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```